# PHP - using foreach to store values of a session array to send to database

Tags: php, database

*Update: Using foreach is not required, but it's the only way i know to access a session array*

I have a session array that contains multiple values in it. I want to insert those values into a database.

Heres what I did:

I would use a foreach to get and display the values in the array, which it correctly does but if i call the variable outside the foreach loop, it only outputs the last value.

Why don't I just insert inside each for loop? I can't because I tried it and it wouldn't insert it because OrderDetails.OrderID may not be NULL meaning I can't insert without a orderID.

Just for tests purposes i tried a nested foreach loop with the insert inside and it displays everything correctly but it displayed it times the number of product IDs there were.

Example Inputs:

```
[prodID] => array{
  [0] => 25
  [1] => 5
}

[qty] => array{
  [0] => 3
  [1] => 5
}
```

The code I given would send 5 prodID and 5 qty

What I want my output to be:

25,5 prodID sent to database

3,5 qty sent to database

I can provide different examples on what i attempted if need be.

```
<?php
//first file
  session_start();

  $prodID = $_SESSION['prodID'];
  $quantity = $_SESSION['qty'];

  $Oquery = "select * from Orders";
  $result = $db -> Oquery($query);

  while($row = $result -> fetch()){
      $orderID = $row['OrderID'];
}
 foreach($prodID as $arrayProd){

  }
  foreach($quantity as $arrayQuantity){

  }
$sql = "INSERT INTO OrderDetails (OrderID,ProductID,Quantity)
                  Values('$orderID','$arrayProd','$arrayQuantity')";
                $exec = $db -> exec($sql);

?>
```

```
<?php
//second file
session_start();

$orderNum = $_GET['orderID'];

$query = "SELECT * FROM OrderDetails WHERE OrderID = $orderNum";
$result = $db -> query($query);
  while($row= $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
        $prodID = $nrow['ProductID'];
        $quantity = $nrow['Quantity'];

        echo"ProdID<br>
        $quantity<br>";
}
?>
```

Comment: In your example, it seems that `prodID` 25 has a `qty` of 3, and `prodID` 5 has a `qty` of 5. Why then you would you want _"25,5 prodID sent to database"_ and _"3,1 qty sent to database"_? Shouldn't it be 25,3 and 5,5?

Comment: typo, my mistake, prodID => 25,5 . Qty = >3,5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly you don't need a 2nd foreach inside the 1st for each.  Basically, 1 foreach will do.  Example:

```
foreach($prodID as $key => $data)
{
 $sql = "INSERT INTO OrderDetails (OrderID,ProductID,Quantity)
        Values('$orderID','$data','$qty[$key]')";
        $exec = $db -> exec($sql);    
}
```

This is air code, untested.  But the idea should help.  Post back if you have a question.

Comment: Works like a charm, never thought about doing this

Comment: Glad it helped you out.  But, remember that 'kmoser' concerns are valid.  I would rethink the entire process.

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems with your approach:

1. You're assuming orders in the `Orders` table will be retrieved in the same sequence as they appear in the `$_SESSION['prodID']` and `$_SESSION['qty']` arrays. Without an `ORDER BY` clause in your `SELECT * FROM Orders`, you really can't make that assumption.
2. You're assuming that the number of orders in the `Orders` table will exactly match the number of items in `$_SESSION`.

Those (and other) questions notwithstanding, this solution might work for you:

```php
<?php
  session_start();

  $prodID = $_SESSION['prodID'];
  $quantity = $_SESSION['qty'];

  $Oquery = "select * from Orders";
  $result = $db -> Oquery($query);

  $i = 0;
  while($row = $result -> fetch()){
    $orderID = $row['OrderID'];

    $pid = $prodID[$i];
    $qty = $quantity[$i];

    // Should probably do some check here to ensure $prodID[$i] and $quantity[$i] are valid, before attempting the INSERT

    $sql = "INSERT INTO OrderDetails (OrderID,ProductID,Quantity) VALUES ('$orderID','$pid','$qty')";

    $exec = $db -> exec($sql);
    $i++;
  }
?>
```

Comment: Same results as my solution, it sends the last value in the array.

Comment: i echo"$pid , $qty "; to see what is being sent to the variable and it correctly outputs them both.